# Is function $F(x)= 2x^2 -3x$ increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus, functions

$F(x)= 2x^2 -3x$.

find the range of $x$ to check whether the function the is strictly increasing and strictly decreasing.

Comment: When the function is strictly increasing, $f'(x)\ge0$ ($f'(x)=0$ is a very special case which I advise caution for)

Comment: Hint : How about computing the derivative and checking the sign ?

Comment: The question itself is poorly phrased.  This function is **both** increasing and decreasing.  The question should be "for what x (or on what intervals) is f increasing or decreasing".

Comment: ^^^ Agreed with user247327

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** :
 Write it as follows $$ 2{ x }^{ 2 }-3x=2{ \left( x-\frac { 3 }{ 4 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }-\frac { 9 }{ 8 } $$

Answer (score 0):

The function 
$$
F(x)= 2x^2 -3x
$$
is strictly increasing (respectively decreasing) for 
$$
f(x):=F'(x)=4x-3>0 \text { respectively } f(x)=4x-3<0 \tag1
$$
this is a linear function which is strictly increasing itself on whole $\mathbb R$. Just observe that $$ f(x)'=4>0$$ holds. Now we just calculate the root $x_0$ of $f(x)$ which is $x_0=\frac 3 4$. There is only one root. This means for all $x>\frac 3 4$ we have $f(x)>0$ and $x<\frac 3 4$ we have $f(x)<0$ vice versa.

Now we conclude by using $(1)$, that $$
F(x) \text{ is strictly increasing } \forall x:x>\frac 3 4
$$
and
$$
F(x) \text{ is strictly decreasing } \forall x:x<\frac 3 4
$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply a small positive increment $h$ to $x$ and compare

$$2(x+h)^2-3(x+h)><2x^2-3x.$$

This can be rewritten

$$4xh+2h^2-3h><0,$$ or

$$4x-3+2h><0.$$

Ignoring $h$, which can be made smaller and smaller, the LHS is positive when

$$x>\frac34$$ and conversely.